# operators and strings in MIPS

Tags: string, operators, mips

I'm trying to figure out how to do this in MIPS:

Example:

```
sum(7,sum(subtraction(0,5),multiplication(division(7,2),3)))
```

Starting from left to right, where `sum`, `subtraction`, `multiplication`, `division` are strings that have the same functions of the basic operators. So, to do the first sum you need 2 numbers so the other sum is called. To do the second sum we need to do the subtraction and so on.

I was thinking to do it with labels but how can i assign an operator to a string?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the following functions that each take two arguments and return a result: `sum, subtraction, multiplication, division`. Then you need to call the functions in the correct order with the correct arguments.

You should study the [MIPS calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#MIPS) to see how to write the functions.